# Swap two charts' visibility in SSRS without an accordion effect

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report, visibility

I have a report with two charts; the charts present similar but not identical data.  I want to show one chart at a time in the report.

When the report runs, one chart has the property `visible`=*true*, and the other has `visible`=*false*.  Both charts toggle from the same textbox.  So far, everything works right -- click on the textbox, and the other chart appears; click on it again, and the first chart appears.  Both charts present the correct data.  The intended effect is for the user to see the desired chart series, with no noticable indication that the report now shows a different chart.

My problem is that even though in Visual Studio's report designer the charts have the same position, the report presents an accordion effect:  The report renders the second chart below where the first chart had been, instead of in the same location.  I'll post screen shots when I can.

The development environment is MS Visual Studio 2008, installed as "SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio."  The report environment is IE11, that being the customer's standard.  (Edit: The customer just upgraded from IE9 to IE11.)

Comment: You need to put both charts inside the rectangle. It will give you perfect result.

Comment: @rajeshpanchal: That worked!  Please turn your comment into an answer so that I may give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap two different charts visibility, you need to put both charts inside one rectangle and then set whatever the condition you have on each one.

So hiding the first chart moves the second one up.

It will surely work.